# Nginx rewrite rule to redirect from requested url to specific url

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect from requested html file to specific location.

for example:

FROM

```
https://example.com/cars/description/ferrari-1-1532.html
```

to

```
https://example.com/car/catalog/ferrari.html
```

I tried this configuration

```
location /cars/description/*.html {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ https://examples.com/car/catalog/request_filename redirect;
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: How do you determine the specific URI? Is it always the first word? Or do you need a map to translate each individual link?

Answer (score 0):

This location should redirect all requests to html files in `/cars/description` directory to this url `https://examples.com/car/catalog/request_filename`

```
location ~* /cars/description/(.+\.(html))$ {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ https://examples.com/car/catalog/request_filename redirect;
}
```